# How to go to fragment from an acitivy

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I wanted to navigate from an activity to fragment and below is the image link in which I have highlighted the code part for navigating to fragment top_news but nothing is happening upon selecting the activity.

I am not understanding the syntax for how to call `top_news` fragment.
Please help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBv7k.png)

Comment: Please include your code in the question. Don't use pictures for codes. And include some pictures on the current output. Include your expected output. This way others can easily helped you out of your problem.

Comment: Could you please show the code, you already got? So others may help you better.

Comment: You have to write your code in the question so that the community may try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's just an example make the same according to your coding.

```
SearchFragment searchFrag = new SearchFragment();
            if(searchFrag != null){
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, searchFrag)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
```

Comment: i want to go top_news.java fragment so what is my fragment container?

Comment: container is one which used to replace the fragment, add this code to your activity

`<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>`

Comment: fragment_top_news is layout ... so fragment_top_news is containers id?

Comment: In that fragment_top_news xml make one framelayout as I have given and give that as Id in coding

Comment: did this and included id yoyo in place of container. but still nothing happening
http://imgur.com/a/rdWoX

Comment: i did what u said.. but nothings happening on clicking